# Is it possible to remove the Pro Tools Unique ID from an audio file?

Tags: pro-tools

I'll soon have a number of projects coming in sequence for which I'd like to prepare some blank "stems" so I don't have to prepare them ahead of each project.

The only problem is that Pro Tools is applying (as it should) the unique ID.

Is there a way I can remove that ID so I can use these clips without having ID collisions?

Edit:

Sorry for the confusion. I will have multiple projects taking place in short order soon.

As part of the process we render blank stems files.  I would like to pre-render blank stem files to then import into these upcoming projects.  Since the projects are unrelated I need to make sure that the blank stems don't have unique Ids when they're imported to the new project.

Comment: Are these PT project files, or WAV files, or what? Also, just curious -- if the IDs are unique, why would you have collisions?

Comment: hi, as it stands it's a bit unclear what you're asking. What do you mean with 'coming in sequence'? Will you need to create stems from sources by others or from your own projects? And can't you just open the stems in another DAW program and re-save it under another name?

Comment: What way are you using the "stems" in?  what is the running time of them?  I don't think you can remove the unique ID but there might be a work around if you can give some more info.

Comment: @JimMack They are files are WAV.  The intent is to have these as pre-rendered empty stems to be imported into different projects.  So we want them to get new ID's when the new project is created.  We just don't want to wait for the stem rendering process every time.

Comment: @coaxmw everything stays within Pro Tools. Many of the projects will have the exact same lengths, providing me an opportunity to build pre-rendered blank stems ahead of time if I can get the unique IDs removed.

Comment: @ArnoudTraa I've updated my main text. Sorry.

Comment: An option that might work for you is to make a template for your upcoming projects with the stem files already in it.  I include audio files in my templates and have never had any conflicts of any sort.

Answer (score 1):

WAV files are RIFF files, with a separate section for metadata like the unique ID. There's at least one file editor that will allow you to view and modify the BWF data, [BWF MetaEdit](http://bwfmetaedit.sourceforge.net/). It should be just what you need. There may be others -- you can search for WAV Metadata Editor or BWF editor to see.

It would be quite easy for a decent programmer to write something to blank out the ID field, or to create a new unique ID each time it will be used.

EDIT: I wrote a small (Windows) utility to update the ID field in a WAV file. I don't know the protocol for this, but if you'd like to try it you can contact me off list. If it's something you find useful I'll be happy to give it to anyone else who wants it.